# Some clarification about the derivative and the derivability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have a question, which may be silly but I have found no proper answer in any textbook so far.
The problem is about derivative and derivability of a function at a point $x_0$.

My question concerns the following doubt: why exactly do I have to check for the derivability thought the difference quotient, to say a function is not derivable at $x_0$?

I mean for example: say $$f(x) = \ln(x)$$

We know the derivative is $$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

and I know that for $x\to 0$ the limit does not exist, for the directional limits are different.
Why can't I reason in this way? Why do I have to use the difference quotient instead?

Wouln't the result be the same?

I also ask for some example, in addition to some clarification...
Thank you so much!

Comment: I wouldn't ask for a derivative at $0$ anyway since $\ln$ isn't defined there.  The better example is to understand something like $f(x)= |x|$ or $f(x) = x^{2/3}$ at $x=0$.

Comment: To make a similar/converse point, will you say that $f'(-1)=-1$ is okay because $\frac{1}{-1}=-1$?

Comment: @Randall Well I wound't ever study the derivative at that point, for $\ln(x)$ has a domain in which there is no $-1$. This is also part of my doubts. 
Why should I study the derivative at points which do not belong to the initial function?

Comment: @Randall I have seen an exercise with a piecewise function, and it was defined as $(1-x^2)\ln(1-x)$ for $x<1$. According to what you said, then it wouldn't make sense to ask for the derivative (derivability) at $x = 1$ (from left), and yet I had to compute it the same... I'm so confused.

Comment: Right, and nor is $x=0$ in the domain of $\ln (x)$, so all is well.  To your second comment, if $x < 1$ then $1-x>0$ so $\ln (1-x)$ makes perfect sense.  Again, no problem.

Comment: @Randall Ok, I'm starting to putting the pieces together... Another thing: I've read that there are cases in which we can skip the difference quotient method, and go straight with $f'(x)$ and the limits. I did not understand what are those cases.

Comment: In a sense, there can be no cases where you "can skip the difference quotient". The derivative is defined as the limit of the difference quotient, and everything you do with the derivative must inevitably find its source in that definition. But that doesn't mean you are stuck using it and only it. There are lots of theorems about derivatives that allow you to calculate them without going back to the definition yourself, such as $(f+g)' = f' + g'$ and $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$. You don't give any information that would allow us to identify the "cases" you are referring, but they will be such theorems

Comment: @PaulSinclair For example: when I had to study the derivability of 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} b e^{x-2} + ax^2 + 1 & x \geq 1 \\ -2ax + 3be^{x-2} & x < 1 \end{cases} $$ in the notes there is no trace of the difference quotient. Just $f'(x)$ and the limits.

Instead when dealing with
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} (2+e)x + 1 & x \leq 0 \\ \ln(e+x) & x > 0 \end{cases}$$

the difference quotient is used. I do not understand why.

Comment: If you look at the individual functions being pieced together for $f$, they both have derivatives at $1$. I assume the question about $f$ is what values of $a, b$ will make $f$ differentiable. If you restrict the values of $a,b$ so that $f$ is continuous there, then both have the same value at $1$. This means the left derivative of $f$ at $1$ will be the derivative of the top function, and the right derivative will be the derivative of the bottom function (which is not true if $a,b$ are such that $f$ is not continuous). Thus what was needed is matching the function and derivative values at $1$

Comment: The same approach would work for $g$. If both of the pieces have the same value for $x = 0$ and the same derivative at $x = 0$, then the derivative of $g$ exists. If they don't agree (which they obviously don't), $g$ is not differentiable there because the left derivative at $0$ and right derivative at $0$ are different. I cannot say why this approach was not used in working that example. Possibly they just wanted to demonstrate using the definition instead.